# Using the value of one field as the column name in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to work out a query in SQL to select records from a secondary table, based on an the answer to one of many fields. The particular field varies from record to record, so I need to use a VALUE from my initial query as a COLUMN title in my secondary query.

I have three table (simplified for this example)

Pass table:

```
PassID  |  PassType  | PersonID |
1       |  3         | 54       |
2       |  4         | 59       |
```

Qualification Required Table:

```
PassType  |  QualificationField |  QualificationAnswer
3         |  Q8                 |  Yes
4         |  Q3                 |  All
```

Person Table:

```
PersonID  |  Name  |...| Q3  |...| Q8   
54        |  John  |...| Non |...| No
59        |  Jane  |...| ALL |...| No
```

Essentially different passes have different criteria that qualifies them for something extra... What I need to determine is for each person, if they have the qualifying criteria based on the pass they have been assigned.

The tables are actually part of a much bigger system and columns in the person table can be added dynamically on different iterations of the database, so I can't significantly change the table structure - I need to be able to extract my answer in the SQL query to determine which people qualify for this 'something extra'.

I already have a query (Q_PersonWithPass) that matches the pass type and qualification requirements, to give me the following fields in one output:

```
PersonID | PassType | QualificationField | QualificationAnswer
54       | 3        | Q8                 | Yes
59       | 4        | Q3                 | All
```

What I need to do now is run a subquery on the person table to look up the column based relating to the QualificationField answer, and check if that field in the Person table matches the QualificationAnswer.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT        PersonID, PassType, QualificationField, QualificationAnswer,
               (SELECT dbo.Q_PersonWithPass.QualificationField
                FROM dbo.Person
                WHERE  (PersonID = dbo.Q_PersonWithPass.PersonID)) AS QualFld
FROM            dbo.Q_PersonWithPass
```

Thus just displays "Q8" or "Q3" in the QualFld rather than the answer "No" or "All"

Is there a way I can get SQL to recognise the value from 'dbo.Q_PersonWithPass.QualificationField' as a column title rather than a variable in the subquery?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You can build dynamic SQL query http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx and execute the final query string with sp_executesql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments under the answer I think the only way of doing what you want is by generating a dynamic sql query.  The code below might not be keystroke perfect, but it should give you an idea of what to do.

The idea is that you work out all of the possible qualification fields, insert them into a temporary table, then build a case statement dynamically based on all of the available options.

```
Select Distinct QualificationField
  Into #TEMPTABLE
  From dbo.Q_PersonWithPass;

DECLARE
@SQLQuery nvarchar(4000),
@QField nvarchar(10)
BEGIN

Set @SQLQuery = 'select PWP.PersonId, PWP.PassType, PWP.QualificationField, PWP.QualificationAnswer,  Case ';

While EXISTS(Select * from #TEMPTABLE)
Begin
    Select Top 1 @QField = QualificationField From #TEMPTABLE;
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'When PWP.QualificationField = ' + @QField + ' Then P.' + @QFIELD + ' ';
    Delete from #TEMPTABLE Where QualificationField = @QField;
End

Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' end AS QualFld FROM dbo.Q_PersonWithPass PWP JOIN dbo.Person P on P.PersonID = PWP.PersonID';

EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLQuery

END;
```

Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for that! I'd played around with dynamic sql but not having used it much I couldn't see how to get it to work.

I just had to make one edit to your code - the quote marks around the  `PWP.QualificationField = ' + @QField + ' ` needed to be  `PWP.QualificationField = ''' + @QField + ''' `but then it all worked great!

Cheers

Comment: The idea is you're just trying to construct the sql statement you want to run into the variable @SQLQuery then execute it at the end.

Comment: If you add 'print @SQLQuery' before the last End statement it will print out what the query is trying to run.  I'm not sure if you're getting an error message when you try now, or it's just not working at all?

Comment: Hi - it's working great now thanks!  I did the print as you suggest to spot the need for the quotes. much appreciated.

Comment: Whilst this works great when I execute it, I can't see a way of being able to use it to feed into other saved 'views'. I can get it to run as a stored procedure, but that won't feed back to my other queries. I've tried wirting it into a table-value fuction but this won't allow me to execute the dynamic sql. Is there a way around this I should be looking at, or is there generally no way of feeding dynamic sql results back into another query?

Comment: The easiest thing to do might be to change the dynamic SQL so that it creates a view instead of spitting out the results.  In the first instance you'd just need to add 'Create view WhateverYouWantToCallIt AS ' onto the start of the @DynamicSQL string.  After this you would then need to change it to 'Alter view...'.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what exactly you want as a result but you can achieve what you are trying to do by using `CASE`. Something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT PersonID, PassType, QualificationField, QualificationAnswer,
    (CASE When p.PersonID = dbo.Q_PersonWithPass.PersonID then 'Yes' 
    else 'No' end ) ASQualFld
    FROM dbo.Q_PersonWithPass LEFT JOIN Person p on p.PersonID = dbo.Q_PersonWithPass.PersonID
```

Comment: In the question it says that columns can be added to the Person table dynamically.  if this is happening I think it would prevent you from writing an explicit case statement that was guaranteed to work?